# Map X Value to String in LiveCharts

Tags: c#, livecharts

I am trying to create dynamic graphs in the library LiveCharts. Currently, I need to be able to map values to a timestamp, as the values I'm graphing are sensor values with a particular name, timestamp in which the value was taken, and the value itself, but the library seems to only be able to take `double` values as an x value. I'd like to be able to set this as a string, and map each point to a particular timestamp.

I've tried several different kinds of methods for this, including manually setting the x axis labels to be the timestamps, using different kinds of points (observable points, GSeries Points, etc), but none seem to have this functionality.

Currently, I'm graphing like this:

```
        private static void CreateNewPlot(Dictionary<string, List<double>> headersAndValues, List<string> timeLables)
        {
            PlotWindow window = new PlotWindow();
            SeriesCollection graph = new SeriesCollection();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<double>> temp in headersAndValues)
            {

                graph.Add(new GLineSeries
                {

                    Title=temp.Key,
                    Values = temp.Value.AsGearedValues()
                });
            }

            window.ChartContainer.Series = graph;
            //window.GSeriesValues = graph;
            window.Show()
```

Is there something I'm missing? Does there exist a way to explicitly assign a point to a value other than a `double`?